# Несколько доменов в одном проекте Django

Tags: python, django, nginx

Хочу сделать доступ к разным приложениям одного проекта Django с разных поддоменов. Сейчас это реализовно через разные ссылки.

```
path('test1/', include('test1.urls')),
path('test2/', include('test2.urls')),
```

В nginx для каждого домена прописан proxy_pass на свою ссылку.

```
location / {
    include     proxy_params;
    proxy_pass  http://unix:/home/myproject.sock/myproject.sock:/test1/;
}
```

Всё работает, но, если использовать в темплейтах тег url, чтобы получить ссылку, то в ссылку добавляется test1. Как это исправить? Может быть есть другие способы реализации такого сценария?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле settings.py добавь список разрешенных доменов

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'test1.example.com', 'test2.example.com']
```

Создай middleware.py в корневой папке проекта и добавьте в него следующий код

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import get_host

class SubdomainMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    
    def __call__(self, request):
        host = get_host(request)
        subdomain = host.split('.')[0]
        
        if subdomain in settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
            request.subdomain = subdomain
        else:
            request.subdomain = None
        
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Добавь middleware в файле settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'path.to.middleware.SubdomainMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Используйте имя приложения вместо префикса в файле urls.py

```
path('', include('test1.urls')),
path('', include('test2.urls')),
```

Comment: Всё заработало. Спасибо огромное!